# Move a line in a file

Tags: beginner, groovy

In Groovy 1.8.6 I need to move a line just before another one. I'm interested in any improvements.

```groovy
fileToChange = new File('.classpath')
linesToKeep = []
fileToChange.eachLine {
    if (it.contains('line to move')) {
        lineToMove = it
    } else {
        linesToKeep.add(it)
    }
}
fileToChange.withWriter { out ->
    linesToKeep.each {
        if (it.contains('line to recognize')) {
            out.writeLine(lineToMove)
        } 
        out.writeLine(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you figured out, moving a line requires two passes:

1. one to determine what  to move and where to move it to,
2. and another to re-write the file with the lines moved.

With some meta-programming you can add a method to the *InputStream* class that would allow you to move a line ahead of another using concise code like this:

```
def source = /line to move/
def dest = /line to recognize/

input.moveLine(source, dest).writeTo(writer)
```

## The meta-programming

You can start with a [Groovy Category](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#categories) that adds the method *[Writable](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Writable.html) moveLine(Object, Object)* to a class, such as an *InputStream*.

```
@groovy.lang.Category(InputStream)
class MoveLineCategory {

    Writable moveLine(Object sourceMatcher, Object destinationMatcher) {
        def (sourceLine, lines) = this.readLines().inject([null, []]) {output, line ->
            switch(line) {
                case ~sourceMatcher:
                    if(!output[0]) output[0] = line
                    break
                case ~destinationMatcher:
                    output[1] << null
                    output[1] << line
                    break;
                default:
                    output[1] << line
            }

            return output
        }

        {Writer writer ->
            lines.each {line ->
                if(line == null) writer << "$sourceLine\n"
                else writer << "$line\n"
            }
        }.asWritable()
    }
}
```

The first pass is similar to your *File.eachLine()* loop except it's done with *Collection.inject()*. The *inject()* method *Closure* returns a *List* containing two items: the line which matched the sourceMatcher regular expression, and a *List* of the entire file with a null inserted as a place holder for the destination of the matched line.

The second pass is actually not executed right way. Instead, a *Closure* coerced into a *Writable* is returned for later use. The returned Writable contains the code needed to write out the changed file.

## Using InputStream.moveLine()

With the Writable on hand, it's now possible to write the file with the line moved. But to even use the *InputStream.moveLine()* method the Category in which it's defined needs to be made available. the Object.use(Class) method does this.

```
def source = /line to move/
def dest = /line to recognize/

use(MoveLineCategory) {
    input.moveLine(source, dest).writeTo(writer) 
}
```

## Complete (self-contained) example

Here's the entire thing in action:

```
@groovy.lang.Category(InputStream)
class MoveLineCategory {

    Writable moveLine(Object sourceMatcher, Object destinationMatcher) {
        def (sourceLine, lines) = this.readLines().inject([null, []]) {output, line ->
            switch(line) {
                case ~sourceMatcher:
                    if(!output[0]) output[0] = line
                    break
                case ~destinationMatcher:
                    output[1] << null
                    output[1] << line
                    break;
                default:
                    output[1] << line
            }

            return output
        }

        {Writer writer ->
            lines.each {line ->
                if(line == null) writer << "$sourceLine\n"
                else writer << "$line\n"
            }
        }.asWritable()
    }
}

def input = ['''This is a line.
And this is another line.
And this is yet another line.
You guessed it, another line.'''] as StringBufferInputStream

def writer = new StringWriter()

use(MoveLineCategory) {
    input
        .moveLine(/And this is another line\./, /You guessed it, another line\./)
        .writeTo(writer)     
}

assert writer.toString().split(/\n/) == [
    'This is a line.',
    'And this is yet another line.',
    'And this is another line.',
    'You guessed it, another line.'
]
```

### Disclaimer

These examples were written with Groovy 2.4.4.

Comment: Very nice, but the asker may need a more basic improvement, your suggestions seem overkill

Comment: The reason the original code is so simple is because the Groovy developers wrote what you may describe as overkill. It is that so-called overkill that makes it possible to write expressive Groovy code. Groovy provides not only elegant abstractions but also the ability to create your own. Two sets of iterations and conditionals replaced with a few lines of code is a drastic improvement.

Comment: Very sensible choice, so in your opinion the added complexity in this case more than pays for itself in the long run. (I was really curious about the reason of all this code, and I did not want to be rude, but text only it is harder to express feeling) :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My approach was influenced by bottom-up programming, which until just recently I did not know essentially means this: to create a programming language in which your application is written in. http://www.paulgraham.com/progbot.html